# jQuery check for certain class won't work

Tags: jquery

For my menu i want to check if an clicked element has e certain classname. If it has, a specific action should follow, otherwise not. Herefore i have the following approach that doesn;t work..

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        if(this.hasClass("noLink")){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("no link here");
        }
    });
});
..
<a href="page.html" title="Title" class="topNav noLink" id="site">Link</a>
```

The code above won't work, it will go to the page.html and i don't get my alert. What am i doing wrong here?

I also tried `if(this.hasClass("noLink") == 'true'){` but that neither did the trick..

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried: if($(this).hasClass("noLink")){ ?

Comment: `this` inside a handler points to a DOM object, not the jQuery object; and as such `this.hasClass()` will fail because there is no such function on a DOM object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        if($(this).hasClass("noLink")){ //`this` plain  is a DOM element
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("no link here");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope, if i click the link it still goes to page.html... I tried that aswell, but with no result.

Comment: Excuse me!! It worked, mistyped a letter!! Thanks in advance!! My bad!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        if($(this).hasClass("noLink")){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("no link here");
        }
    });
});
..
<a href="page.html" title="Title" class="topNav noLink" id="site">Link</a>
```

You need to use `$(this)` instead of `this`.